# Unable to load azure Blob file into Hive table in HDINSIGHT

Tags: azure, hadoop, hive, hiveql, azure-hdinsight

I'm new Hadoop, i got myself stuck in one of basic question in loading only single blob file data into hive table. I'm creating table based on File name emp.dat.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Employee(ID int, manager string,Code int,Name string, Year int, Month int, Salary int,Age int) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION 'wasb://practice@XXXblobstore.blob.core.windows.net/emp.dat/'
```

When i execute above command, I'm getting error below:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.
MetaException(message:Got exception: java.io.IOException
Cannot create directory wasb://practice@XXXblobstore.blob.core.windows.net/emp.dat/
```

I also tried a different approach to create the table with no location of any wasb. And after that, run the following command:

```
LOAD data inpath 'wasb://practice@XXXblobstore.blob.core.windows.net/emp.dat/' overwrite into table Employee
```

It throws error incorrect sytax at wasb url.

Please help me that on this issue. Is it compulsion to use directory instead of file name. Is it possible to create external table by giving only filename.

My Another condition is : If we give directory name and it contains 2 files which are of different schema.. how does it loads all the file data into table.

Is there way to change default container from hive command

Comment: solution proposed by Victor F is the right way to do it. In azure, you will need to store data in folders within the container. When you starting creating multiple tables, storing all the data files in default folder is not advisable.

Answer (score 1):

I think following should work (as long as you have emp.dat inside this emp directory)

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Employee
(
    ID      INT,
    Manager STRING,
    Code    INT,
    Name    STRING,
    Year    INT,
    Month   INT,
    Salary  DOUBLE,
    Age     INT
)
ROW FORMAT
    DELIMITED
    FIELDS           TERMINATED BY '\t'
LOCATION 'wasb://practice@XXXblobstore.blob.core.windows.net/user/emp'
;
```

Comment: thanks victor. But I'm looking for mentioning LOCATION 'wasb://practice@XXXblobstore.blob.core.windows.net/user/emp/emp.dat.' rather than directory emp.  here emp/emp.dat is not present in default directory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I finally found a way to load file data into hive table
LOAD DATA INPATH 'wasb:///tempdata/emp.dat' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE Employee;

This works only for Default container because the authority part of the URI's do not match if the containers are different even though they belong to same storage account. please refer to below URL

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/en-US/22cf9a71-cce7-4765-a78e-2dc569d69a8a/hive-path-is-not-legal-azure-storage?forum=hdinsight